# Copy specific amount of files to changing directory with Batch script?

Tags: batch-file

So I am trying to create a batch script that takes photos from an SD card and places it in a sub-directory. I then need to take a specific amount of photos (eight) and place them in a separate sub-directory, then take the next eight photos and place them in a subsequent sub-directory. In other words, say I have 32 photographs. My script needs to copy them to say C:\Photos. I then need the script to take the first eight photos and copy/paste them into C:\Photos\1. Then I need the next eight photos to be copied/pasted into C:\Photos\2 and so on.

I already know how to copy the files from one directory to another (kind of). All of the sub-directory folders are created earlier within my script. So I have this section of code:

```
set cnt=0
set folder=1

for %%P in ("C:\Photos\") do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    if exist %%P\*.jpg COPY %%P\*.jpg C:\Photos\%folder%
    echo count = %cnt%
)
```

The goal of this code (well, what I want it to do) is, for each file in the C:\Photos directory, add one (1) to the cnt variable, and display the value of that cnt variable. The problem is, the way the code sits, it copies the files properly, but does not count. It only counts one (1) file. However, if I add *.jpg to the first part like this

```
for %%P in ("C:\Photos\*.jpg") do (
```

It counts the proper amount of files, but the copying doesn't work. What gives?

Also, since for debugging purposes, I want it to echo the current count after each file is counted/copied. The way I have it, the count seems to change, but won't display.

Edit: New problem. I have my test images labeled as img1, 2, 3 and so on. When I run the code, it seems to go through them in a random order. If I run through 32 files the order is as follows: Img 1, 3, 13, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 11,  12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 22, 9, 10, 21, 23, 24, 31, 32, 17, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 and 30. Seems pretty random to me and the order is the same every time the script is ran.

Answer (score 0):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set cnt=0
set folder=1

for %%P in ("C:\Photos\*.jpg") do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    echo(COPY "%%P" C:\Photos\!folder!
    echo count = !cnt!
    SET /a switch=cnt %% 8
    IF !switch!==0 (set /a folder+=1)
)
```

First issue is to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` because within a code block (parenthesised series of commands) any `%var%` is replaced by the contents of the variable **at the time the block is first encountered** - see endless items on SO about `delayedexpansion`.

Using `delayedexpansion`, whereas `%var%` refer to the original value, `!var!` refers to the run-time value - the current value as it changes.

I established a new variable, `switch` which is calculated as `count` *mod* 8, so it is zero after each group of files in complete. Interpret `!switch!` and when it is zero, increment `folder`

Note that `%%P` will contain the actual filename as read from the directory, so there's no real point in checking it for existence - all you need to do is `copy` it to the destination.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

---

Revision to transfer in "name" order

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set cnt=0
set folder=1
REM set "sourcedir=c:\photos"
SET "sourcedir=u:\sourcedir"

for /f "delims=" %%P in ('dir /b /on /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg"') do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    ECHO(COPY "%sourcedir%\%%P" C:\Photos\!folder!
    echo count = !cnt!
    SET /a switch=cnt %% 8
    IF !switch!==0 (set /a folder+=1)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Report for testing:

```
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 0.jpg" C:\Photos\1
count = 1
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 1.jpg" C:\Photos\1
count = 2
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 10.jpg" C:\Photos\1
count = 3
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 11.jpg" C:\Photos\1
count = 4
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 12.jpg" C:\Photos\1
count = 5
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 13.jpg" C:\Photos\1
count = 6
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 14.jpg" C:\Photos\1
count = 7
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 15.jpg" C:\Photos\1
count = 8
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 16.jpg" C:\Photos\2
count = 9
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 17.jpg" C:\Photos\2
count = 10
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 18.jpg" C:\Photos\2
count = 11
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 19.jpg" C:\Photos\2
count = 12
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 2.jpg" C:\Photos\2
count = 13
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 20.jpg" C:\Photos\2
count = 14
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 21.jpg" C:\Photos\2
count = 15
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 22.jpg" C:\Photos\2
count = 16
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 23.jpg" C:\Photos\3
count = 17
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 24.jpg" C:\Photos\3
count = 18
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 25.jpg" C:\Photos\3
count = 19
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 3.jpg" C:\Photos\3
count = 20
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 4.jpg" C:\Photos\3
count = 21
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 5.jpg" C:\Photos\3
count = 22
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 6.jpg" C:\Photos\3
count = 23
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 7.jpg" C:\Photos\3
count = 24
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 8.jpg" C:\Photos\4
count = 25
COPY "u:\sourcedir\file 9.jpg" C:\Photos\4
count = 26
```

The question of "order" is debatable. You appear to be reading from a SD card which reports the files in the sequence that they are entered in the directory. You can order the file in **name** sequence (that's the meaning of `/o:n` in the `dir` subcommand) but that is strictly alphabetical order - as shown. It would be *possible* to have the sequence in order of the value of the numerical part, but it would be quite a lot of work.

You could also change `/o:n` to `/o:d` which would change the odering to datestamp-order, which may be closer to what you want.

Comment: Awesome, that works great! New problem though, which I have also added to the original post. I have my test images labeled as img1, 2, 3 and so on. When I run the code, it seems to go through them in a random order. If I run through 32 files the order is as follows: Img 1, 3, 13, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 2, 11,  12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 22, 9, 10, 21, 23, 24, 31, 32, 17, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 and 30. Seems pretty random to me and the order is the same every time the script is ran.

Comment: Also, if I lay the code out how you have it (ie set, echo(copy), echo count, etc) it does not work for me. It ends up doing the echo(copy) part for each file before displaying a single echo count. I am able to echo the count for each file if I place that before the echo(copy) but if I have it after it doesn't read until all of the files have been gone through. This makes the switch variable not work properly as well.

Comment: Sorry - I can't follow what your sying with that last comment. I've added a report listing from my testing...

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is that is that when I ran the code, everything after the "copy" line would not show until everything was "copied". Thus, giving the wrong count variable. I have not tried your revised code yet. Can you explain it though? (for /f "delims=" %%P in ('dir /b /on /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg"') do ) and why that makes it go in order as well as what Goto :EOF is?

Comment: The `dir` command uses `/on` which is order-by-name. `/a-d` means "no directorynames` `/b` means "basic form - filename only, no headers etc.` so the `dir` command is a series of lines of text, one filename to a line in alphabetical order. This is processed by the `for/f` one line at a time. `goto :eof` (the colon is critical) mean "goto the physical end of file." It's redundant here, but I put in in through habit - it means that if I decide to add a subroutine, then it's simply a matter of adding the code and the main routine will skip over the added subroutine.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond. I am trying to have the files go in numerical order (img1, img2, img3, img 4, etc). I tried changing /on to /od (do the colons matter? It doesn't seem to make a difference to me) but I still can't get it. I get the order (1, 11, 12, 13 etc, 2, 21, 22, 23 etc) or the random order that I mentioned above. Ordering by date would work but again, /od doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is it possible to actually go in order by actual file name or would I have to create some sort of list/dictionary wizardry to make this work?